# How to store multi connected waypoints

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create a basic 2D road system on a grid. Currently I have a list of staight lines but they are not connected to each other.

The part I am stuck on is how I construct the data and store my data so I know which waypoint points to which ever waypoint (more than one way point can connect to any other way point).

So currently if you image i have this as my data:

```
var point      = [];
    point[0]   = {'x':2,'y':6};
    point[1]   = {'x':2,'y':8};
    point[2]   = {'x':6,'y':9};
    point[3]   = {'x':7,'y':2};
```

Now suppose point 0 connects to points 2 and 3. And point 1 connects to point 3.

What would be the best way to store the information that these points are linked, also allowing me then to look up and obtain properties of the object relating to a connected waypoint (which would mainly be useful for pathfinding in the future).

For example I may need to find a waypoint at a given x or y position. Or i may want to obtain relevant waypoint data that are connected to for example point 1, such as their x and y position and what ever waypoints may connect to them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The road network can be represented by an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). Basically, each point will be given a list (which could be implemented by an array) containing the indices which can be reached from it. In your example, this can be expressed as follows.

```
var point      = [];
point[0]   = {'x':2,'y':6, 'neighbors':[2,3]};
point[1]   = {'x':2,'y':8, 'neighbors':[3]};
point[2]   = {'x':6,'y':9, 'neighbors':[0]};
point[3]   = {'x':7,'y':2, 'neighbors':[0,1]};
```